# Mvc property default value for child class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How to set default value for a child class property in model?

```
public class TestModel
{
    public ChildModel1 ChildModel1 { get; set; }
    public ChildModel2 ChildModel2 { get; set; }
}

public class ChildModel1
{
    public ChildModel1()
    {
        this.MyProperty = string.Empty; //this dont's work.
    }
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class ChildModel2
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

In controller's action.

```
public ActionResult Index(TestModel model)
{
    var value = model.ChildModel1.MyProperty;  //this is null if value not entered.
}
```

Currently, I'm using this which is not correct way of doing.

```
var value  = model.ChildModel1.MyProperty != null ? model.ChildModel1.MyProperty : "";
```

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: why this.MyProperty = string.Empty; doesnt work ? what the error you get ?

Comment: I simply get null in action for these property. there is no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your child model constructors initialize the value of their string properties but you never actually initialize the child model instances themselves in the main model.

In addition to your `string.Empty` assigment in the child model, you also need to instantiate the `ChildModelX` instances in your `TestModel`:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public ChildModel1 ChildModel1 { get; set; }
    public ChildModel2 ChildModel2 { get; set; }

    public TestModel()
    {
        ChildModel1 = new ChildModel1();
        ChildModel1 = new ChildModel1();
    }
}
```

Also, if your form doesn't pass a string value, the model binder will initialize it to null. Try using a backing field for the property and returning `string.Empty` if it's null:

```
private string _myProperty;

public string MyProperty
{
    get { return _myProperty != null ? _myProperty : string.Empty; }
    set { _myProperty = value; }
}
```

Comment: Yeah! that worked. I should have thought using ternary operator in model itself instead of in individual action. Thanks